# compare column of one file to range from other file and keep lines that fall into range

Tags: r, bash, awk

I have two files:

1) a

```
        code    chr    position    score            
code123947     10       13417     0.9221900
code456747     10      717559     1.0000000
code523452     10     1554421     0.5315330
code223534     10     2354490     0.0479356
code654321     10     4461920     0.9144420
code345635     10     5564649     0.7069120
code214234     10      115746     0.7191680
code654332     10      133160     0.4205290
code263562     10      135203     0.7178790
code987654     10      230894     0.5351590
```

2) b

```
chr      start   stop
10   60523   751339
10   751339      1523544
10   1523544     2254500
10   2254500     3352699
10   3352699     4572274
10   4572274     5983762
10   5983762     7171484
10   7171484     8774665
10   8774665     10249396
```

I need to subset file "a" for only lines in which, for matching "chr" the "position" falls within "start"-"stop" of file "b"

I have tried the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ range[$1,$2,$3]; next }
FNR==1
{
for(x in range) {
split(x, check, SUBSEP);
if($2==check[1] && $3>=check[2] && $3<=check[3]) print $0
}}
' b a
```

but this just returns the an unaltered "a"

I have also tried to deal with this in R:

```
 a[a$V2 == b$chr && a$V3 >= b$start && a$V3 <= b$stop, ]
```

which I know is useless because this compares the columns side-by-side. it throws an error telling me that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

I also attempted to use "foverlaps" in data.table with "b" columns as the key

unfortunately, this is the best I have right now.

Any suggestions? the output I am seeking is:

```
code    chr    position    score 
code456747     10      717559     1.0000000
code523452     10     1554421     0.5315330
code223534     10     2354490     0.0479356
code654321     10     4461920     0.9144420
code345635     10     5564649     0.7069120
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- merge(a, b, by = 'chr')
x <- x[x$V3 >= x$start && x$V3 <= x$stop, ]
```

You can merge the two dataframes together and then filter like you had before.

Answer (score 0):

similarly with `join` assisted `awk`

```
$ join -12 -21 a b | awk '$5<=$3 && $3<=$6{print $2,$1,$3,$4}'

code456747 10 717559 1.0000000
code523452 10 1554421 0.5315330
code223534 10 2354490 0.0479356
code654321 10 4461920 0.9144420
code345635 10 5564649 0.7069120
code214234 10 115746 0.7191680
code654332 10 133160 0.4205290
code263562 10 135203 0.7178790
code987654 10 230894 0.5351590
```

PS. files need to sorted on the key field